# is PIM sm supported in packet tracer 5.3.0.0088

Tags: networking

I am using packet tracer 5.3.0.0088 but I am not finding any support for enabling Ip multicasting in global config mode neither PIM SM in interface mode inbetween two routers.

```
r1(config)#ip mult
r1(config)#ip mult
r1(config)#ip ?
  access-list       Named access-list
  default-network   Flags networks as candidates for default routes
  dhcp              Configure DHCP server and relay parameters
  domain            IP DNS Resolver
  domain-lookup     Enable IP Domain Name System hostname translation
  domain-name       Define the default domain name
  forward-protocol  Controls forwarding of physical and directed IP broadcasts
  ftp               FTP configuration commands
  host              Add an entry to the ip hostname table
  inspect           Context-based Access Control Engine
  ips               Intrusion Prevention System
  local             Specify local options
  name-server       Specify address of name server to use
  nat               NAT configuration commands
  route             Establish static routes
  ssh               Configure ssh options
  tcp               Global TCP parameters
r1(config)#ip
```

Kindly let me know how to enable PIM or atleast ip multicasting?